# Select 1 row from each child table, but ignore previously selected values

Tags: mysql, subquery, temp-tables

May I ask for some help with the following please?

I have 3 tables in my DB like this …

```
wordDates
dID        wDate
1       ‘2015-01-01’
2       ‘2015-01-02’
3       ‘2015-01-03’
4       ‘2015-01-04’
5       ‘2015-01-05’

Words
wID    dID    word
1      1      dca
2      1      mno
…
28     4      xyz
29     4      abc
30     4      abc
```

The third table is created from a query ...

```
CREATE TABLE faveWords
SELECT DISTINCT word, count(word) 
FROM words
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY word;
```

which gives me a table similar to ...

```
word    wordCount
abc     8
dca     8
mno     7
dad     6
```

Basically it is just a table of ranked words. I have a fiddle of the database [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a494c/9).

My problem is that I would like to get the top word for each wDate, limit the full results and finally ignore previously selected values for each iteration of the query.

Imagine there were values such as this in the words table ...

```
dID(FK)    word
1          abc    // 'abc' = Top word in faveWords 8
1          dca
```

Above, The query would select 'abc' as it is the most popular word in faveWords.

```
2          abc   // Need to ignore this word
2          xyz    
2          dad
```

On the next iteration, I need to ignore 'abc' and find the most popular word from 'xyz' and 'dad'. In my fiddles case, the next selection would be 'dad'.

```
3          abc  // ignore
3          dca 
3          xyz
3          dad  // ignore
```

The third iteration the only values to choose from would be 'dca' and 'xyz' as 'abc' and 'dad' have already been selected.

And so it goes until I have a list of the most popular words between two dates. However, finally, I would like to get a top n of those selections (based on faveWords.wordCount). So if my LIMIT was 3 I would have an ending dataset of ...

```
'abc' // This scored 8 for wordCount in faveWords from the fiddle
'dad' // This scored 6
'dca' // This scored 8
```

The query I have to generate the results is ...

```
SELECT w.wID, w.dID, wd.wDate, w.word, fw.word
FROM words w
INNER JOIN worddates wd ON wd.dID = w.dID
INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT sw.word, sfw.wordCount
        FROM words sw
            INNER JOIN worddates swd ON swd.dID = sw.dID
            INNER JOIN faveWords sfw ON sfw.word = sw.word
        WHERE swd.wDate >= '2015-01-02'
          AND swd.wDate <= '2015-01-07'
        GROUP BY sw.word
        ORDER BY sfw.wordCount DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS fw ON fw.word = w.word
ORDER BY w.wID
LIMIT 3;
```

However, it doesn't even come close to what I want to retrieve from the tables. It just returns 'abc' for each row of my LIMIT of 3.

May I ask for you help please? How can I get each days faveWord, but ignore previously selected values ?

Is it possible to add word selections to a 'tempTable' that could be used as an 'ignore' table ?

Thank you.

EDIT for StrawBerry :-

The query would select an initial list of ...

```
|   1 | 2015-01-01 |   4 | abc  |       faveWords score 8
|   2 | 2015-01-02 |   6 | dca  |       faveWords score 8
|   3 | 2015-01-03 |  12 | bcd  |       faveWords score 3
|   4 | 2015-01-04 |  15 | dad  |       faveWords score 6
|   5 | 2015-01-05 |  17 | mno  |       faveWords score 7
|   6 | 2015-01-06 |  23 | dbd  |       faveWords score 1
....
```

And then the final 'LIMIT 3' would select

```
|   1 | 2015-01-01 |   4 | abc  |       faveWords score 8
|   2 | 2015-01-02 |   6 | dca  |       faveWords score 8
|   5 | 2015-01-05 |  17 | mno  |       faveWords score 7
```

from the initial list.

As for why. I'm trying to produce a top n list of **unique** words over, say 3 months, but I don't want to list words more than once. I mean, I didn't want final results like ...

```
|   1 | 2015-01-01 |   4 | abc  |
|   2 | 2015-01-02 |   5 | abc  |
...
|   n | 2015-mm-dd |   x | abc  |
| n+1 | 2015-mm-dd | x+1 | abc  |
```

NB - Apologies, When you reach the line ...

```
|   1 | 2015-01-01 |  26 | dca  |
```

There are some issues with the fiddle data. The dID's should continue 7 etc... and the Dates should increment too. A lazy copy and paste on my behalf.

Edit 2 :-

[Better fiddle Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0f1e/2)

Comment: Think I have found a way around this. Will test and update the Q.

Answer (score 0):

Let's back up a bit. So you might have an intermediate result set that looks like the following. From this, which results would you want and why?

```
SELECT d.*
     , w.wid
     , w.word 
  FROM worddates d 
  JOIN words w 
    ON w.did = d.did;
+-----+------------+-----+------+
| dID | wDate      | wid | word |
+-----+------------+-----+------+
|   1 | 2015-01-01 |   1 | dca  |
|   1 | 2015-01-01 |   2 | mno  |
|   1 | 2015-01-01 |   3 | xyz  |
|   1 | 2015-01-01 |   4 | abc  |
|   2 | 2015-01-02 |   5 | abc  |
|   2 | 2015-01-02 |   6 | dca  |
|   2 | 2015-01-02 |   7 | dad  |
|   2 | 2015-01-02 |   8 | dad  |
|   3 | 2015-01-03 |   9 | abc  |
|   3 | 2015-01-03 |  10 | abc  |
|   3 | 2015-01-03 |  11 | dca  |
|   3 | 2015-01-03 |  12 | bcd  |
|   4 | 2015-01-04 |  13 | xyz  |
|   4 | 2015-01-04 |  14 | abc  |
|   4 | 2015-01-04 |  15 | dad  |
|   4 | 2015-01-04 |  16 | dca  |
|   5 | 2015-01-05 |  17 | mno  |
|   5 | 2015-01-05 |  18 | xyz  |
|   5 | 2015-01-05 |  19 | def  |
|   5 | 2015-01-05 |  20 | mno  |
|   6 | 2015-01-06 |  21 | dca  |
|   6 | 2015-01-06 |  22 | bcd  |
|   6 | 2015-01-06 |  23 | dbd  |
|   6 | 2015-01-06 |  24 | dad  |
|   6 | 2015-01-06 |  25 | mno  |
|   1 | 2015-01-01 |  26 | dca  |
|   3 | 2015-01-03 |  27 | bcd  |
|   4 | 2015-01-04 |  28 | xyz  |
|   4 | 2015-01-04 |  29 | abc  |
|   4 | 2015-01-04 |  30 | abc  |
|   7 | 2015-01-07 |  31 | dac  |
|   4 | 2015-01-04 |  32 | abc  |
|   8 | 2015-01-08 |  33 | dad  |
|   9 | 2015-01-09 |  34 | dca  |
|   8 | 2015-01-08 |  35 | mno  |
|  11 | 2015-01-11 |  36 | xyz  |
|   8 | 2015-01-08 |  37 | def  |
|   9 | 2015-01-09 |  38 | hij  |
|  10 | 2015-01-10 |  39 | him  |
|  12 | 2015-01-12 |  40 | efg  |
|   9 | 2015-01-09 |  41 | and  |
|  11 | 2015-01-11 |  42 | dad  |
|  12 | 2015-01-12 |  43 | mno  |
|  10 | 2015-01-10 |  44 | dca  |
|   9 | 2015-01-09 |  45 | hij  |
|   7 | 2015-01-07 |  46 | def  |
|   7 | 2015-01-07 |  47 | efg  |
|   9 | 2015-01-09 |  48 | mno  |
+-----+------------+-----+------+
```